# Error with php connection to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I just got a raspberry pi 3 and I thought I would use it to learn php except I am having a frustrating issue.

I have a pi 3 running raspbian and I have installed php5, apache2, MySQL and phpmyadmin.  I can create test html files in /var/www/html and browse them from my windows PC and the pi and they work.  I created a php file with the following code and this also works as expected.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World!</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo "Hello World"; ?>

</body>

</html>
```

The problem comes when I want to connect to MySQL.  I created the following file (from a youtube video) and placed it in /var/www/html and when I browse to it with Edge or on the pi itself I get 'Edge cannot find the page' or a blank page (one the pi).

```
<?php

//opens connection to mysql server
$dbc = mysql_connect('192.168.0.9','pi','raspberry');

if (!$dbc){
    echo("not connected:" mysql_error());
}

//select database

$db_selected = mysql_select_db("testDB", $dbc);
if (!$db_selected){
    echo("cant connect :" . mysql_error());
}

?>
```

Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: If mysql is on the pi try `'localhost'` as the first argument

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices.

Comment: Why makes you think that the mysql connection is the issue? I suggest you take a look into your http servers error log file. That is where you can read in details what the precise issue is, in what line in what file. You _cannot_ develop php scripts without monitoring that file. Not unless you are a big fan of endless guessing games.

Comment: This `echo("not connected:" mysql_error());` needs to be concatenated. `"not connected:"` completes the string. In the `if (!$dbc){` block. Voting to close a typo..

Comment: That youtube tutorial probably is out of date and teaching you out of date/bad practices. I'd recommend one using `mysqli` or `PDO` and parameterized queries.

Answer (score 0):

Note that:

- If you are using PHP 5.5+ the mysql_* functions are deprecated
- Maybe you are not seeing the warnings because your php.ini "display_errors" directive is not set on.
- Try something as:
  var_dump(mysql_error()) to get extra info about what is happening there...
- Use mysqli_* functions. Them are almost the same as mysql_*